# How do I set the timeout when using the DetectText method of the Google Vision API? I need a sample source

Tags: c#, google-vision

I want to run OCR using the DetectText method of the Google Vision API. I want to prepare for the situation that the OCR program that I develop is disconnected in the middle of running. So I want to generate an error if there is no response within 2 seconds after calling the DetectText method. (Default is 10 minutes, set to 600000 milisecond). Thank you for your help. In the sample source will be even more helpful.

Thank you.

```
using Google.Cloud.Vision.V1;          

var image = Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.Image.FromFile(sFilename);
var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
var response = client.DetectText(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

The DetectText method calls additional CallSettings parameters.

```
using Google.Cloud.Vision.V1; 
using Google.Api.Gax;
using Google.Api.Gax.Grpc;

var timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
CallSettings callSettings = CallSettings.FromCallTiming(CallTiming.FromExpiration(Expiration.FromTimeout(timeout)));

var image = Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.Image.FromFile(sFilename);
var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
var response = client.DetectText(image, null, 0, callSettings);
```